# Newrork error IOException : failed top connect to ip, connection failed: ETIMEDOUT

Tags: java, android, sql

I am getting the above error whilst using the below code, I am not sure if it something to do with the connection string? Does it have something to do with me not using the correct ip maybe?

```
  Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example.");
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
    String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    //test = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class;
    String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP/TABLENAME;encrypt=false;user=SECURE\\username;password=password;instance=instance;";
    Log.i("Android"," connString");
    String username = "secure\\username";
    String password = "password";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
    Log.w("Connection","open");
    Log.i("Android"," Con Open");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery("select FeedURL from [dbo].[RSS_Source]");
    Log.i("Android"," Query");

    //Print the data to the console
    while(reset.next()){


      Log.w("Data:",reset.getString(3));
//                      Log.w("Data",reset.getString(2));
        }
    conn.close();


    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), 
                   //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("FAIL", null);

    }
```

Comment: server or client may be blocked by a firewall .. check that

Comment: Not sure, it could be that. Is there any way to get more information from the error message? Like what exactly is causing the time out?

Comment: write a log on both file, it may be issue with your port too